# Ошибка программы с библиотекой brawlstars.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, brawlstars.py

У меня есть код для бота дискорд:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ui import View, Button
from discord.utils import get
from discord import *
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import brawlstars as bs

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%ch', intents=discord.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def pstat(ctx, playertag):
    player = bot.get_player(f"{playertag}")
    club = bot.get_club(player.club.tag)
    if club is not None:
        members = bot.get_club_members(club.tag)

        best_player = max(members, key=lambda member: member.trophies)
        em = discord.Embed(title="Статистика игрока:", discription=(best_player.name, f"- {best_player.trophies} "))

bot.run("Токен")
```

Но при вводе соответствующей команды выходит ошибка:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_player'
```

Вопрос - как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вызвать `get_player` у бота дискорд, а не у `bs.Client`